# Get missing imports in batches

Tags: go

When I clone a project written in golang, it is normal that a lot of imports like 
'github.com/XXXX' are missing. Is there any way to get these imports in batches by a command? or I am suppose to get them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of golang projects now use dependency management so you should look for that first. e.g a Glide.lock (glide) or Gopkg.lock (dep - the way people are moving now) file present in the root of the project.

https://github.com/golang/dep

https://golang.github.io/dep

if dep is used and you have it installed then `dep ensure` will set the dependencies up for you and make sure you get the versions the author intended

if a project is not using dependency management you can just get the packages with  `go get ./...` but I don't think you will be guaranteed the correct versions (e.g if the author was pinned to a version tag for a dep)

If you run `dep init` it sets up dep on a project and will attempt to resolve the correct versions, however this doesnt always work if the stars dont align (e.g I have seen issues with dependencies using gopkg.in)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `go get` to get "remote" packages. Quoting from [Command go: Download and install packages and dependencies](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies)

> Get downloads the packages named by the import paths, along with their dependencies. It then installs the named packages, like 'go install'.

You may use the `-v` flag in all of the following commands, and so you will see what `go get` is doing under the hood.

You may use the `-d` flag if you just want to download the packages but you do not want to install them.

The examples use the example remote package `github.com/somebody/somepackage`, but obviously it works for other packages hosted outside of github.com.

For more information, see the official doc: [Command go](https://golang.org/cmd/go/), or type `go help get`.

---

To get a single package with all the dependencies of that package and install them, use

```
go get github.com/somebody/somepackage
```

To get a package with all its dependencies, and all other packages rooted at that path (along with their dependencies), and install all of them, use:

```
go get github.com/somebody/somepackage/...
```

Quoting from Command go:

> An import path is a pattern if it includes one or more "..." wildcards, each of which can match any string, including the empty string and strings containing slashes. Such a pattern expands to all package directories found in the GOPATH trees with names matching the patterns.

To get a package with all its dependencies (and "subpackages") **including dependencies of tests**, and install all of them, use:

```
go get -t github.com/somebody/somepackage/...
```

To update a package you already have, use:

```
go get -u github.com/somebody/somepackage/...
```

To fetch dependencies of a package you already have (which is not necessarily from a remote location):

```
go get path/to/package/name/...
```

Or go to its folder and then you may use a relative path:

```
go get ./...
```

Comment: To clarify: `go get github.com/somebody/somepackage` will get a package **and** its dependencies, but only of that package. If there are sub-packages that have dependencies that are not imported by `somepackage`, that's where `somepackage/...` is required.

Comment: @TimCooper You're right, thanks, it wasn't very clear. Edited.

Comment: This is a good explanation of go get command but op should check for dependency management first, I believe 'go get' just pulls master for everything which may not be what the author intended

Answer (score 2):

try using `go get ./...` in root of your project